# Why base.AuthorizeCore(httpContext); is true before any authentication or authorisation?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0, authorization

In my custom Authorize Attribute:

```
 public class AuthorizeUserAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{

    public string AccessLevel { get; set; }

    protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
    {
        var isAuthorized = base.AuthorizeCore(httpContext);
        if (!isAuthorized)
        {
            return false;
        }

        string privilegeLevels = string.Join("", httpContext.Session["UserRole"]);
        privilegeLevels = privilegeLevels.Trim();
        AccessLevel = AccessLevel.Trim();
        string[] usersWithAcces = AccessLevel.Split(',');
        foreach (string u in usersWithAcces)
        {
            if (privilegeLevels.Equals(u))
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
    protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(
                     new RouteValueDictionary(
                         new
                         {
                             controller = "UserAccount",
                             action = "LogIn"
                         })
                     );
    }
}
```

}

var isAuthorized is always true. In my logic it should look like this:

1. First attempt to access protected method isAuthorized should be false.
2. User is redirected to LogIn page.
3. If user's details are recognised isAuthorized is true and next statements are executed.

Probably I'm missing something but if somebody could tell me why it is always true I would be grateful.

Comment: Have you tried using `HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated` instead of `base.AuthorizeCore`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what happens in AuthorizeCore(HttpContext):

```
protected virtual bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
    {
        if (httpContext == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("httpContext");
        }

        IPrincipal user = httpContext.User;
        if (!user.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            return false;
        }

        if (_usersSplit.Length > 0 && !_usersSplit.Contains(user.Identity.Name, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        {
            return false;
        }

        if (_rolesSplit.Length > 0 && !_rolesSplit.Any(user.IsInRole))
        {
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
```

As you can see this means that the current user is already logged in (there is a cookie for him in the browser). Assuming you use FormAuthentication my best guest is that you are not properly disposing the cookies.

Try accessing the protected resource in an incognito browser window. If that doesn't work check out your LogOff controller, it should look like something along these lines:

```
public ActionResult LogOff()
{
   FormsAuthentication.SignOut();

   return RedirectToAction("Login", "Account");
}
```